# Windows 2019 server NTP increases memory utilisation by acquiring page table

Tags: ntp, windows-server-2019

We started with a brand new windows server 2019 datacenter edition and installed an infrastructure monitoring agent on it and strictly no other program. The machine had 8 GB of memory. As part of monitoring NTP offset from sync'd host we scheduled an exe. The problem started after 10-11 days, the memory utilisation had increased to significant level >80%. On analysis we found it was a gradual increase and using RAMMAP we saw every time the exe will run it will leave behind 24k of memory in PAGE Table with 0 B in Private. Moreover this issue is specific to windows server 2019 we tried following same steps on windows server 2012 machine and it worked perfectly fine with no memory creeping issues.

**Memory usage per task manager:**
[image]

**Process Tab:**  We tried to look for processes using task manager Resource monitor  and even WPT xperf utility but could not find any other process consuming such a high amount of memory.

**Process Tab:**
[image]

**RAMMAP:** As it can be seen here the exe scheduled has died already but is still holding page table memory.

**RAMMAP:**
[image]

**Total RAMMAP use counts:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54cYw.png]

This has lead to an unanswerable gradual memory spike. Can it be related to some windows server 2019 specific drivers or system files which is used by NTP?

Comment: Which ntpq.exe binary did you install, I didn't think that came with Windows? How are you running it on a schedule?

Comment: We are using meinberg's ntpq